# Make column span full width if sibling column does not exist

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm attempting to have somewhat dynamic behavior in a CSS grid while having the underlying grid rules be static.

I've created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/w7z8kw8jxl?fontsize=14) to better illustrate what I want to happen. When the GREEN box is deleted from the DOM, I want RED to cover the entire first row, and when GREEN is visible, I want RED / GREEN to have a 2fr / 1fr allocation on the first row.

I've scoured the docs to try to find a way to do this, but the only solutions I find involves manipulating the CSS at "runtime". Is it possible to achieve this with CSS only?

```js
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector("button.toggle-green");
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
const yellow = document.querySelector(".yellow");

const getGreen = () => document.querySelector(".green");
const createGreen = () => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "green";
  div.innerText = "GREEN";
  return div;
};

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const green = getGreen();
  if (!green) {
    grid.insertBefore(createGreen(), yellow);
  } else {
    green.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2px 2px;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="red">RED</div>
  <div class="green">GREEN</div>
  <div class="yellow">YELLOW</div>
</div>
<button class="toggle-green">Toggle green</button>
```

Comment: Frankly, this sounds like something flexbox could fix,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* make it work with *CSS Grids*, but you've to *set the widths carefully* to set it up:

- Create a *wrapping grid* using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(66.66vw, 1fr))` - note the *minimum width* here is in *viewport units*.
- Now set `min-width: 33.33vw` for the *green section*.

In the code below - note the use of `calc` - this adjusts *horizontally* for the `grid-gap`. See demo below:

```js
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector("button.toggle-green");
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
const yellow = document.querySelector(".yellow");

const getGreen = () => document.querySelector(".green");
const createGreen = () => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "green";
  div.innerText = "GREEN";
  return div;
};

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const green = getGreen();
  if (!green) {
    grid.insertBefore(createGreen(), yellow);
  } else {
    green.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(calc(66.66vw - 2px), 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2px 2px;
  width: 100vw;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  min-width: 33.33vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="red">RED</div>
  <div class="green">GREEN</div>
  <div class="yellow">YELLOW</div>
</div>

<button class="toggle-green">Toggle green</button>
```

---

**Flexbox solution**

But I'd suggest a *flexbox approach* which you would be familiar with already - use a *wrapping flexbox* and set:
- `flex: 1` to the *green* div,
- `flex-basis: 100%` to the *yellow* section, and
- `flex: 2` the *red* section.

See demo below:

```js
const toggleBtn = document.querySelector("button.toggle-green");
const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
const yellow = document.querySelector(".yellow");

const getGreen = () => document.querySelector(".green");
const createGreen = () => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.className = "green";
  div.innerText = "GREEN";
  return div;
};

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const green = getGreen();
  if (!green) {
    grid.insertBefore(createGreen(), yellow);
  } else {
    green.remove();
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100vw;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  flex: 2;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="red">RED</div>
  <div class="green">GREEN</div>
  <div class="yellow">YELLOW</div>
</div>

<button class="toggle-green">Toggle green</button>
```